# Odoo 14: How can i get all records that exists in case of one2many field and showing them in current window instead of popup

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-14

Problem : im using One2many field i want to display all records that already exists instead of showing them in popup  [what im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwzPV.png)  -  [The xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmtNx.png)  -
[My goal its to make it like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuNv0.png)

Comment: I not really sure I totally understand what you want. But try to set widget many2many_tags on one2many instead of many2many.

Comment: Thank you jo541
I already use it & it works but i want to make them line by line as list instead of tags

- Purpose :
One2many field when im trying to add some cause i need to get the causes that already exists & if i want to add record i'll add it in tree view without popup

Comment: That should be done with an "embedded" list view and the attribute `editable` (values: bottom or top) on it. The first answer should do the trick. But another thing: naming the one2many field `whatever_id` is against the odoo naming guidelines and also not very logical, because there could be more than one record behind this relation. That's why the [guideline](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/misc/other/guidelines.html#symbols-and-conventions) prescribes `_ids` as suffix for x2many fields.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your image in question and have problem in xml file. Removed widget from the causes_id field and removed mode attribute from the tree tag.

Try with this code:

```
<field name="causes_id" mode="tree">  <!-- add more mode if you want like form, kanban -->
    <tree string="Registered" editable="bottom">
        <field name="field_1"/>
        <field name="field_2"/>
        <field name="field_x"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```